# send data from one method to onCreate Activity method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I get data from Activity in method called onConnected,Im get current location:longitude,latitude.How can I put this data to fragment?Yes,I know about Bundle and how deliver data trough that way,but I cant create Bundle in onConnected method and setArguments to fragment,because I created fragment in onCreate Activity method.I created class variable longitude and latitude,but in onCreate that variables = 0.How can I send data to fragment?I need to get current location in Activity and send it to fragment.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is create an `Interface` and let them(Your activity and fragment) implement.
The idea is basically to define an interface inside a given fragment A and let the activity implement that interface.

Once it has implemented that interface, you could do anything you want in the method it overrides.

The other important part of the interface is that you have to call the abstract method from your fragment and remember to cast it to your activity. It should catch a ClasCastException if not done correctly.

[here](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/) you can see.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the fragment is added by the activity in which you are getting the required data, you can directly pass the data using the fragment instance from the activity. The activity will have reference to the fragment. Hence, call a method of the fragment from that instance in Activity.

Comment: I would use @sourabh's solution for transferring data from fragment to activity.